# cue.enter event for video tag doesn't work?

Tags: html5-video

I tried the following code (using the javascript commands for the html5 video tag) and it failed.  I'm wondering if there is something very visible that I'm doing wrong.  I'm trying to make the video pause whenever a cue is entered...
here is the code:

```
var cue0 = new TextTrackCue(20.200,20.200, ' woman in defensive karate pose');
cue0.id = 'cue0';
cue0.onenter="function() {myPlayer.pause();}";
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be a lot of problems from your code. I see, that startTime is equal to endTime, which means, that your cue is never entered.

I made a simple [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/trixta/WvJ75/)

```
cue = new TextTrackCue(5, 15, "woman in defensive karate pose");
```

Comment: I tried to duplicate your code, and could not get it to work, until I added the "polyfiller" script, and the modernizr script.  This means that my own code is valid, but it just doesn't work on browsers that should support it.  My question to you is, what is polyfiller and modernizr for, and what do I need to include in "modernizr" to have everything I need to get this to work?

Comment: What browsers are you using? The code should work in Chrome 24+ and Opera 12.5+ without Modernizr/polyfiller (see http://jsfiddle.net/WvJ75/7/). All other browsers including IE10 or Safari 6 need those extra files for polyfilling. Modernizr is for feature detection and polyfiller is for polyfilling. You find it here http://afarkas.github.com/webshim/demos/index.html

Comment: As you say, I find that your polyfiller code is not needed in Opera.  It is needed in IE-10 though.  In chrome, I find that it does not solve one of the issues.  Chrome was playing subtitles for me without polyfiller, but it was not pausing when entering a cue.  (I had made the "onenter" event trigger a pause).  With polyfiller, it still fails to do this, but here IE-10 does well.  With polyfiller, IE-10 is able to pause the video on cue-entry.

Comment: I have a test file at: http://www.rateforsuccess.com/TestCueStop.htm - this uses polyfill.  I also have test file without polyfill: at http://www.rateforsuccess.com/TestCueStopPure.htm.   You should be able to confirm what I say about Chrome, IE and Opera.